# Infinite Scrolling without ajax using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, web-sql

I want to create infinite scroll in jquery mobile web application.I want to scroll the page without using ajax.Is there any possibility to do that?

Comment: yes there is.  use `$(window).scroll()`

Comment: What do you mean by "without using ajax"? if you don't want ajax just load the whole page.

Comment: @VahidND I stored data's in local database (Websql) from that i m retrieving and loading..if 100 data's are there it is taking more time to load in single shot.That is what i m trying with infinite scrolling without ajax.

Answer (score 4):

If your data isn't really infinite, you may store everything in the page and show the ones that needs to be shown.

For example (not tested, but to give you an idea):

**HTML**

```
<div class="scrollable-data"><!-- ... --></div>
<div class="scrollable-data"><!-- ... --></div>
<div class="scrollable-data"><!-- ... --></div>
<div class="scrollable-data"><!-- ... --></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var $doc=$(document);
var $win=$(window);

// hide everything that is out of bound
$('.scrollable-data').filter(function(index){
    return ($(this).scrollTop() > $doc.height());
}).hide();

var DATA_INCREMENT=5;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    // test if at the bottom
    if ($doc.height()-$win.height()-$(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
        // show the <DATA_INCREMENT> (5) next hidden data tags
        $('.scrollable-data:hidden:lt('+DATA_INCREMENT+')').show();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.