# JQuery: Infinite (finite) scrolling on pre-loaded data

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll, jquery-waypoints

I have data and I have form Div Grid of 4 column each.

I want Infinite (finite) scrolling on pre-loaded data.

I want to show next Grid data after scroll down and reach to bottom of main div.

I don't want to do it with Ajax call I already have data and formed Div Grid.

Any Idea to do it with Waypoint Infinite Scroll ?

**UPDATED :-**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
    element: $('.infinite-container')[0]
  });
});

function MyFunction() {
  alert("HI");
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    var div = "<div class='infinite-item'> <div class='square-box'> <div class='square-content'> test </div> </div> <div class='square-box'> <div class='square-content'> test test </div>";

  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
.square-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #4679BD;
  display: inline-block;
}
.square-box:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
.square-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
  <!DOCTYPE html >
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Tutorials</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="infinite.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="infinite-container">
      <div class="infinite-item">
        <div class='square-box'>
          <div class='square-content'>
            test 1
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='square-box'>
          <div class='square-content'>
            test 2
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='square-box'>
          <div class='square-content'>
            test 3
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='square-box'>
          <div class='square-content'>
            test 4
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="infinite-item">
        <div class='square-box'>
          <div class='square-content'>
            test 11
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='square-box'>
          <div class='square-content'>
            test 12
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='square-box'>
          <div class='square-content'>
            test 13
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='square-box'>
          <div class='square-content'>
            test 14
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="infinite-item">
        <div class='square-box'>
          <div class='square-content'>
            test 111
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='square-box'>
          <div class='square-content'>
            test 112
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='square-box'>
          <div class='square-content'>
            test 113
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='square-box'>
          <div class='square-content'>
            test 114
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="infinite-item">
        <div class='square-box'>
          <div class='square-content'>
            test 1111
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='square-box'>
          <div class='square-content'>
            test 2222
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=' square-box'>
          <div class='square-content'>
            test 3333
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='square-box'>
          <div class='square-content'>
            test 4444
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="infinite-more-link" href="">More</a> 
    <!-- javascript:MyFunction(); return false; -->
  </body>
  <style type="text/css">
  </style>

  </html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: And... what have you tried so far?  (there should be a button next to comments to add this text).   Next, search SO, this will be a duplicate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146298/onclick-show-next-divs

Comment: dont wnt to use click event, want to do it with scroll reach at bottom of div ...

Comment: Without knowing what you've tried so far, it's impossible to tell if you're stuck at showing next x records or at detecting when the area has been scrolled.  How showing next x records is *triggered* is irrelevant if that's the problem (click or scroll).

Comment: I have solved my problem with following link , first made Divs hidden , except first Grid Divs , after scrolling shown next Grid ...
still any help will be accepted ...
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20042643/3425489

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Also paste [this code](http://pastebin.com/37LYjDCj) and put in different file (and don't forget to include in  it). I also suggest to put all styles in separate file too. You also need to have test2.php (or however you want, but in that case you will need to update jQuery script at the bottom of code). It works because I tested:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Tutorials</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js" data-semver="2.2.0" data-require="jquery@*"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.square-box {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #4679BD;
    display: inline-block;
}
.square-box:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
}
.square-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="infinite-container">
  <div class="infinite-item">
    <div class='square-box'>
      <div class='square-content'>
        test 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='square-box'>
      <div class='square-content'>
        test 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='square-box'>
      <div class='square-content'>
        test 3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='square-box'>
      <div class='square-content'>
        test 4
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="infinite-item">
    <div class='square-box'>
      <div class='square-content'>
        test 11
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='square-box'>
      <div class='square-content'>
        test 12
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='square-box'>
      <div class='square-content'>
        test 13
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='square-box'>
      <div class='square-content'>
        test 14
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="infinite-item">
    <div class='square-box'>
      <div class='square-content'>
        test 111
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='square-box'>
      <div class='square-content'>
        test 112
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='square-box'>
      <div class='square-content'>
        test 113
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='square-box'>
      <div class='square-content'>
        test 114
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="infinite-item">
    <div class='square-box'>
      <div class='square-content'>
        test 1111
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='square-box'>
      <div class='square-content'>
        test 2222
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class=' square-box'>
      <div class='square-content'>
        test 3333
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='square-box'>
      <div class='square-content'>
        test 4444
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<nav id="pagination">
    <p><a class="infinite-more-link" href="test2.php">More</a></p>
</nav>

 <script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var win = $(window);

    // Each time the user scrolls
    win.scroll(function()
    {
        if ($(document).height() - win.height() == win.scrollTop()) {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'test2.php',
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(html) {
                    $('.infinite-container').append(html);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: For example, your current code in website (HTML one) that is responsible for displaying information/tables. You know, tables, divs, paragraphs, etc. At least then I would imagine how more accurately show jQuery.

Comment: I have updated my answer with complete code. Don't forget to upvote/mark as solved if that helped! :)

Comment: ty for reply, but I already have data loaded in my jsp and I have formed Grid of that data, I don't want to use ajax call for loading data again... can't upvote your solution. 14 reputation only

Comment: Well, you didn't mention about that and what you would like to avoid using. :/ EDIT: I believe you are still able to mark answer as accepted I think? Anyways, I currently can't offer any other option as I have limited time to be in here.